# Multiple users with omniauth during development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm doing my firat Rails app with Omniauth and was wundering what the best approach to the followin problem is.

The application only allows users to signup/signin with their LinkedIn account - I don't wanna manage a User database and all users have an LinkedIn account anyway.

The application allows the users to interact with each other, but since the app only accept LinkedIn users to log in, how can I test the functionality of the app during development.

I can only login with one user (my own LinkedIn account) and I need at least one more to see if everything is working.

Should I create a few fake LinkedIn accounts and use these for testing the app?
Or what's the best way to add more users to the app without a lot of LikedIn accounts?

Kenneth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a User model (and I hope you have it) you can create any users in the rails console:

```
> User.create! :name => "someuser", :email => "someuser@example.com", :password => "somepassword"
```

Make sure to add all required fields.

Comment: I do have a User model - the one Omniauth uses.

But I don't have a login page, where I can login in with a username/password.. because I use a link to the omniauth provider login..

match '/auth/:provider/callback'  => 'sessions#create'

Comment: You dont need it. Use rails console (>> rails c) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html